# Install vnc.exe with powershell without an authorization prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to install a vnc.exe with powershell script , and I don't want to receive message box which ask me if I want to install this application , is possible to skip over this step with a powershell script or parameter .

Thank you !

Comment: you don't need powershell, you need a silent installation option for the installer, which should be readily available in their documentation(would link to this but I don't know if the 'vnc.exe' you are using is for realvnc or another client).  This question is likely better asked over at ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Actually I want to make a powershell script which install the vnc.exe remotely on some servers and PC's . I succeeded up to point , but a have a problems with that message box which ask me if i want to install this aplication .

Comment: Which brand of VNC?  RealVNC, TightVNC, UltraVNC, etc, etc..........

Comment: Right, you need to choose a silent install, which is an option that needs to be passed to the installer itself. If you post your existing code and let us know which vnc app is being installed we can help working out what the option is and how you need to call it

Comment: $pathvargs = {E:\UltraVNC_1_2_12_X86_Setup /S /v/qn }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $pathvargs .

Comment: For remotely install i will use PCExec to run this PS script which will be copied for all PC's and after instalation the PS script will be deleted , but i don't know how i can skip for the msg box

Comment: I succeed but with a bath script  E:\UltraVNC_1_2_12_X86_Setup /SP- /VERYSILENT /NORESTART , you just need to run CMD with admin rights

Comment: I assume "PCExec" is really PSExec.. if you have a working install string why not use PSExec to do the install?  iirc it has a switch that will copy the .exe over for you before starting the install.

Comment: psexec @d:\list.txt -u domain\username -p password-c D:\PowerShell\bat\installuvnc1.bat 

d:\UltraVNC_1_2_11_X86_Setup/verysilent/loadinfo = C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC /norestart

Comment: psexec @d:\list.txt -u domain\username -p password-c D:\PowerShell\bat\installuvnc1.bat 

d:\UltraVNC_1_2_11_X86_Setup/verysilent/loadinfo = C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC /norestart                                                                             I try to run this script with psexec but I have errors , what is wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

See all the options at the end of http://www.uvnc.com/install/installation.html

Comment: While this theoretically may provide help for the question asked, it is important to include the details here as well.  Furthermore, the question was about how to install silently via PowerShell - albeit where most of us see that as unnecessary.